# Outlook add-ins on-send feature - replace URL string in message body

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is it possible to detect and replace a URL string in the message body using the on-send feature for Outlook add-ins?

**Requirement**

If a specific URL is detected in composed message when the user clicks send, I want to automatically replace the URL with another URL string.

A related requirement - is it possible to modify/replace URL strings in the message body for external messages as they arrive in the user's inbox?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> is it possible to modify/replace URL strings in the message body for external messages as they arrive in the user's inbox?

Web add-ins work in the context of a single item. You can use EWS or Graph API for accessing other items and making changes on them.

> Is it possible to detect and replace a URL string in the message body using the on-send feature for Outlook add-ins?

Yes, it is. Note, beside OfficeJS APIs you can use EWS for making changes on the email being sent. See [Call web services from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/web-services) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Do you know if any modification to the message as described would take place before a message is signed, if the Outlook user had the option to sign/encrypt using S/MIME etc.

Comment: Can you please clarify what modifications you were referring to and as well as how is the user signing the email?

Comment: Depending on your scenario, you can try using `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` and `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.setAsync()` to modify the body of an item. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.body?view=outlook-js-preview#methods